# c# ошибка в приложении

Tags: c#

При нажатии кнопки выходит ошибка:

```
Описание:
  Stopped working

Сигнатура проблемы:
  Имя события проблемы: CLR20r3
  Сигнатура проблемы 01:    cctalk.exe
  Сигнатура проблемы 02:    1.0.0.0
  Сигнатура проблемы 03:    591d5531
  Сигнатура проблемы 04:    CctalkLib
  Сигнатура проблемы 05:    1.0.0.0
  Сигнатура проблемы 06:    591d5530
  Сигнатура проблемы 07:    7b
  Сигнатура проблемы 08:    c7
  Сигнатура проблемы 09:    System.TimeoutException
  Версия ОС:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.320.65
  Код языка:    1049
```

При нажатии на кнопку:

```
public void StartPoll()
{
  if (_t != null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Stop polling first");

  lock (_timersSyncRoot)
  {
    if (!_rawDev.Connection.IsOpen())
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Init first");
    _t = new Timer(TimerTick, _rawDev, 50, PollPeriod);
  }
}
```

Далее

```
    void TimerTick(object state)
        {
            lock (_timersSyncRoot)
            {
                var buf = _rawDev.CmdReadEventBuffer();

                var newEventsCount = _lastEvent <= buf.Counter ? buf.Counter - _lastEvent : (255 - _lastEvent) + buf.Counter;
                _lastEvent = buf.Counter;

                if (newEventsCount != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(newEventsCount, buf.Events.Length); i++)
                    {
                        var ev = buf.Events[i];
                        if (ev.IsError)
                        {
                            String errMsg;
                            var errCode = (CoinAcceptorErrors)ev.ErrorOrRouteCode;
                            _errors.TryGetValue(ev.ErrorOrRouteCode, out errMsg);
                            BeginInvokeErrorEvent(new CoinAcceptorErrorEventArgs(errCode, errMsg));

                        } else
                        {
                            CoinTypeInfo coinInfo;
                            _coins.TryGetValue(ev.CoinCode, out coinInfo);
                            var evVal = coinInfo == null ? 0 : coinInfo.Value;
                            var evName = coinInfo == null ? null : coinInfo.Name;
                            BeginInvokeCoinEvent(new CoinAcceptorCoinEventArgs(evName, evVal, ev.CoinCode, ev.ErrorOrRouteCode));
                        }
                    }

                    var eventsLost = newEventsCount - buf.Events.Length;

                    if (eventsLost > 0)
                    {
                        BeginInvokeErrorEvent(new CoinAcceptorErrorEventArgs(CoinAcceptorErrors.UnspecifiedAlarmCode,
                                                                             "Events lost:" + eventsLost));
                    }

                    _lastEvent = buf.Counter;
                }
                // TODO: signal unexpected device reset, when device`s event cointer go to 0
            }


        }
```

Comment: Слишком много инфы (*сарказм*)

Comment: И? Где код? Исключение по таймауту, вот и всё, больше при текущих данных сказать невозможно.

Comment: Кода очень много, сюда выкладывать?

Comment: Главное на некоторых компьютерах работает, а на чистом win7 нет, поставил все net frameworkи.

Comment: Покажите как минимум ту часть кода, которая вызывает исключение. И неплохо было бы приложить StackTrace.

Comment: Модифицируйте приложение, подпишитесь на необработанные исключения и залогируйте stack trace (он есть в свойствах исключения). Результаты включите в вопрос.

Comment: Вообщем проблема была в net framework 3.5 на клиенте, а надо было net framework 3.5 SP1